# error with the TextView

Tags: android, textview

I do not know why `findViewById(R.id.tv01)` is not defined. I mean there is an error when I call `R.id.`

I checked the .xml file and it looks fine.

I know this problem might sound silly but I really do not know what is wrong with it.

code:

```
TextView tv01;
TextView tv02;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main); 

    float [] R = new float[3];
    float [] values = new float [3];

    tv01 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv01);

    SensorManager.getOrientation(R, values);
}
```

.xml:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="R = " />
```

Comment: a quick check if you are using android.R or your.package.name.R?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have an array called `R`, which shadows the R class, and there's no id property to a float array. Change its name.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main); 

    float [] rfa = new float[3];
    float [] values = new float [3];

    tv01 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv01);

    SensorManager.getOrientation(R, values);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should rename your array from 'R' to another name.
For example:

```
...
float [] r = new float[3];
float [] values = new float [3];
...
```

You already have class with name 'R' which contains all ids.